# upgrading to jquery -1.10.2.min.js disturbs UI of Phonegap App android and gives error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

i upgraded to **Cordova 2.9.0.js** and its **jar file**,**JQuery-1.10.2.min.js**,**JQuery-Mobile-1.4.0.css and .js ,**  here is how i added JQM,JQUERY in my script tags:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app/app-style.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/simpledialog.min.css"/> 
    <link href="css/lib/mobiscroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
     <script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jqm.page.params.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/cordova.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/lib/simpledialog2.js"></script> <script src="js/lib/jSignature.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/lib/jq-dateformat.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/lib/mobiscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.autosize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
```

**My problem is when i am trying to deploy my app first time its working fine its UI and everything is fine in Samsung Galaxy S3 Android 4.2** [image: deploy first time image]

but when i am trying to run 2nd time from Eclipse then its Layout disturbs its button color changed why this is happening? 
[image: running 2nd time image]

and as well as i m getting **error** in console:
 **09-04 22:51:33.459: D/CordovaLog(26299): file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js: Line 5 : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

**
while if i am removing app from device and deploying it again then everything works fine.
previously i was using **Cordova-2.7.0 , Jquery-1.7.2.js , Jquery-mobile-1.1.1.min.js and its css**.but i did nt see such type of problem.

---

Answer (score 0):

You must put jquery migrate plugin when you upgrade jquery in your Project...

you can Download jquery migrate plugin from [HERE](http://jquery.com/download/).
And Give Reference to in your Project

like

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Hope Your Problem solve from this..

Comment: but i was previously using jquery 1.7.2 may  i need to use jquery-migrate-1.7.2.js?

Comment: Hello @user1668447 see this link https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Comment: no this does not solve my problem  issue is same as i uploaded image